# Linq Grouping with a sum

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sum

Hi All i have the following code

```
var deptSalesQuery = from d in db.DashboardFigures
join s in outlets.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)) on d.OutletNo equals s
            where (d.TypeOfinformation == "DEPTSALES")                                
            select new DeptSales
                    {
                      Dn = (int)d.Number,                                                 
                      On = d.OutletNo,
                      Qs = (double)d.Value_4,
                      Se = (double)d.Value_2,
                      Si = (double)d.Value_3
                    };
```

What i want to do is group the query by 'Dn' which is 'd.Number'and return 
the sum of (double)d.Value_4 , (double)d.Value_2 , (double)d.Value_3. I have looked on the forum and some people have asked a similar question but for some reason its not working for me. Can anyone help ?

I have changed the code to

```
var deptSalesQuery = from d in db.DashboardFigures
join s in outlets.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)) on d.OutletNo equals s
                                 where (d.TypeOfinformation == "DEPTSALES")
                                 group d by d.Number into newGroupedresult
                                 select new DeptSales
                                 {   

                                     Qs = (double)newGroupedresult.Sum(d => d.Value_4),
                                     Se = (double)newGroupedresult.Sum(d => d.Value_2),
                                     Si = (double)newGroupedresult.Sum(d => d.Value_3)
                                 };
```

but its not grouping, Its showing the individual records. Also I normally have Dn = D.Number, its not allowing me to put this.

Answer (score 0):

```
deptSalesQuery
.GroupBy(x => x.Number)
.Select(g => new 
             { 
                Dn = g.Key, 
                Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Value_2 + x.Value_3 + Value_4)
             });
```

Comment: Hi Selman22, Thanks for that, I kind of got the idea, but im struggling to put it into the code above. Its frustrating as Ive been coding for 17 years and now learning LinQ and it just not sticking !!!

Comment: @Alpesh what  do you mean? you can assign it like `deptSalesQuery = deptSalesQuery.GroupBy(x => x.Number) .... ` or enclose your query with parentheses and add the `(your query).GroupBy(x => x.Number).Select(..) ` after it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Its working now. I initially has a problem that I was thinking it was not grouping, In the end it was a mistake on my data